# how to access the fields value in custom view twig. drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

I have created view with 3 fields.

1. title: type: text.
2. image. type: image.
3. video. type: file.

How to get the value of each of these fields in my view twig.

Here's my code:

```
{% for row in rows %}
   <div>{{ row.content.title}}</div>
   <img src="{{ row.content.image}}"/>
   <video controls="controls" src="{{ row.content.video }}"></video>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for any one have struggled with this is how I found it.

```
{% for row in rows %}
   <div>{{ row.content['#row']._entity.title[0].value }}</div>
   <img src="{{file_url(row.content['#row']._entity.field_image.entity.fileuri)}}"/>
   <video controls="controls" src="{{file_url(row.content['#row']._entity.field_video.entity.fileuri)}}"></video>
{% endfor %}
```